# como fazer a funcao tap no android notification

Tags: javascript, java, android

Olá, tenho a seguinte situação, é um chat, e o usuario recebe mensagem.. quero que quando o app estiver minimizado ele receba um alerta... A parte do alerta ja fiz e esta funcionando:

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void notificacao(String mensagem){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app)
                .setContentTitle("Nova mensagem")
                .setContentText(mensagem)
                .setSound(soundUri); //This sets the sound to play

        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


    }
```

no javascript quando recebe a mensagem chamo:

```
var notificacao_mensagem="mensagem a enviar";
window.JSInterface.notificacao(notificacao_mensagem);
```

Ele funciona, só que quando clico em cima da notificacao nao faz nada.. queria que ao clicar nela o programa que está minimizado retornasse a aparecer

Answer (score 1):

Falta adicionar o bloco

```
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Para fechar uma notificação programaticamente, você deve conhecer o id  da mesma e poderá cancela-la usando o método *cancel*

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.cancel(id_notificacao);
```

Alternativamente, Você pode criar um evento com o método *addAction* para sair da sua notification.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, id_notificacao);
    PendingIntent pullOfIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

......

```
   mBuilder.setContentIntent(notifyPIntent);
```

......

```
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, "Sair", sairIntent)
```

referencias: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html